# Set desktop mode when using WebView to surf the web on mobile

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create a `WebView` control in `ContentPage` and set its Source property and so on. It works well with no question.

But I'm wondering if the website I visited can be set to desktop mode.

Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can implement a custom renderer.

Create a Custom Renderer(DesktopWebViewRenderer.cs) in Android folder:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(DesktopWebViewRenderer))]
namespace forms.Droid
{
    public class DesktopWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public DesktopWebViewRenderer(Context context): base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Settings.UserAgentString
                = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";

        }
    }
}
```